# Generalization of Euler theorem for homogeneous polynomials

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, projective-geometry

Euler's theorem for homogeneous polynomials is well known. If $F:\mathbb{R}^{n}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a homogeneous polynomial, then we have: $x_{1}\frac{\partial F }{\partial x_{1}} + ... + x_{n}\frac{\partial F }{\partial x_{n}} = deg(F)F$ .
My question is: are there generalizations of this formula for higher order derivatives?

Comment: What kind of generalizations are you looking for? Of course, you could apply operator $ \sum_{i} x_i \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} $ to this identity again, but that's not very interesting I think.